# Column name: character '#' not supported

Tags: hive, character, special-characters, hiveql, create-table

I am trying to create a hive table with a column name ending with `'#'` but I am getting the following error.

> ParseException line 1:linenum character '#' not supported here

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Read what [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-SelectSyntax) says:

In Hive 0.13 and later, column names can contain any Unicode character (see [HIVE-6013](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6013)). Any column name that is specified within backticks (`) is treated literally. Within a backtick string, use double backticks (``) to represent a backtick character.

Use backticks like this:

```
select 1 as `#column with #`;
```

Result:

```
#column with #  
1
```

If you create table with such column, then it will be possible to query only using backticks. This is not convenient though quite possible.